# Set the path in environment variable by batch file

Tags: batch-file, path, environment-variables

i am trying to set path in the environment variable dynamically by batch file by the below command

`SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:/abc/xyz"`

what is this doing is , its taking the system variable path also and appending with user path ,i don't want the system path, only the user variable should be update not along with the system path

Comment: Does this help:- http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

use `set` instead of `setx`

`set` will set a local variable in the running cmd-window (and "daughter-processes).

`setx` will set a global variable for all future cmd-windows.